# for loop not working in function - php

Tags: loops, for-loop

I have problem with `for` loop not working correctly because they loop only one time and variable after implementation have only one `value = 0`.

```
function pokaz($a,$b){

    for($poma=0;$poma<=400;$poma++){
        $potab2=explode("a",$tab[$poma]);

        $xa=$potab2[0];
        $xb=$potab2[1];

        echo $poma;

        if($xa!="b"){

            if(($xa==$a)and($xb==$b)) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;   
            }
        }

    }
    $poma=-1;
}

 pokaz(5,5);
```

Comment: 1) Maybe can you explain what did you expect? 
2) Which variable has 0 value?
3) I suggest you use the debugger to have step by step processing. Very efficient way to detect bugs at Runtime.

Comment: Return will exit your fuction and thus also your for loop

Answer (score 0):

Please check code, I have corrected it, in PHP "and" is not an operator you have to user "&&" for and condition. I think PHP Server must has generated error but your error_reporting would be 0, thus you didn't get errors in script.

```
    function pokaz($a,$b){

    for($poma=0;$poma<=400;$poma++){
        $potab2=explode("a",$tab[$poma]);

        $xa=$potab2[0];
        $xb=$potab2[1];

        echo $poma;

        if($xa!="b"){

            if($xa==$a && $xb==$b) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;   
            }
        }

    }
    $poma=-1;
}
pokaz(5,5);
```

Comment: the && show me syntax error, problem is in table becose echo show empty value.

Comment: can you write last line with echo pokaz(5,5); I think there is no error in given code, i think you just need to print result.

Comment: but echo is in function

Answer (score 0):

I delete else command and variable in for - work ok - but when I called this variable on tab when I call echo then php show empty tab but in real is full.

$de=0;

$plik = fopen('kropki.txt','r');

$tekst=fgets($plik, 10000);

fclose($plik);

$tab=explode("c", $tekst);

foreach($tab as $key){

```
$tt++;

if(!empty($key)){

$tab[$tt]=$key;     

}

$z++;
```

}

for($i=$z+1;$i<=400;$i++){

```
$tab[$i]='bab';
```

}

function pokaz($a,$b){

```
for($poma=0;$poma<=400;$poma++){

$string=$tab[$poma];

$potab2=explode("a",$string);

$xa=$potab2[0];

$xb=$potab2[1];

echo $tab[$poma]."<br>";

if(($xa!="b")and(!empty($potab2[0]))){

    if(($xa==$a)and($xb==$b)){

        return 1;

        }
    }

}
```

}

pokaz(5,5);

---

### and hereis txt file

```
cac11a11cacac10a12cac9a12c8a11c8a10c8a9c9a8c10a8c11a9c11a10
```